# Port 55555 on Mac OS Big Sur already in use

Tags: macos, big-sur

I've noticed the port `55555` looks like it is already in use on Mac OS Big Sur.

If you run `nc -l 55555` it shows an error. `Address already in use`

But nothing answers if you telnet it, and nothing shows up on `lsof -i tcp:55555` too. Very odd behaviour.

Confirmed on several different machines.

Is there any way to figure out what is running and release it?

Comment: I faced the same issue and unfortunately have not been able to find a resolution. There is a discussion on Apple Developer Forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668506. Reaching out to Apple we got a response saying the port 55555 is now reserver for 1st party application; tho I'm hoping there will be a patch freeing this port coz we have 100k+ docker downloads depending on this port. I'd like to stay updated on this so if you hear anything about let us know. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up changing my service to run on a different port